# typing prop in Vue class-based component in typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-class-components

Working on a class based component in a typescript context, and wondering about a typescript error I keep encountering.

The following is my component code:

```
<template>
  <b-message :type="statusToBuefyClass">
    <p>PLACEHOLDER</p>
  </b-message>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
@Component({
  components: {},
  props: {       <----------------- typed prop
    status: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    }
  }
})
export default class Foo extends Vue {

  // explicitly type status
  status!: string         <----------------- explicit, redundant typing

  get statusToBuefyClass(): string {
    const statusHash: {
      init: string
      active: string
      inactive: string
      archived: string
    } = {
      init: 'is-warning',
      active: 'is-success',
      inactive: '',
      archived: 'is-danger'
    }

    // return statusHash
    return Object(statusHash)[this.status]  <------ error is triggered by this
  }

  bar = this.status <------------- this would also error, if not explicitly typed above

  mounted() {}
}
</script>
```

The above works without compilation errors.  But, if I remove the explicit typing of `status` -- `status!: string` -- I get the following error:

```
Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Foo'.
```

I've found numerous article and issues that are similar, but none seem to quite match my situation.  In my `tsconfig.json`, I have the following set, which some posts suggested could help:

```
"strict": true,
"noImplicitThis": true,
```

Any thoughts or insight?  Is there an alternative to passing props AND then typing them again inside `export default class Foo extends Vue {...`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how I missed this, or how sustainable this feels, but found a solution.

Trick was to use `@Prop` decorator.  The following compiles without error:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
@Component({
  components: {}

  // <--------------- props removed from here...

})
export default class Foo extends Vue {

  @Prop(String) status!: string // <--------- use @Prop decorator to type and capture prop from parent

  get statusToBuefyClass(): string {
    const statusHash: {
      init: string
      active: string
      inactive: string
      archived: string
    } = {
      init: 'is-warning',
      active: 'is-success',
      inactive: '',
      archived: 'is-danger'
    }

    // return statusHash
    return Object(statusHash)[this.status] // <------- no more compilation errors here
  }

  mounted() {}
}
</script>
```